American / Canadian young man who leaves civilization
I once watched this movie where the lead character was a American/Canadian teenager who gets disillusioned with life/State of the world and leaves .. goes into the wilderness in search of peace or answers for the questions/confusions he had. 
I remember one scene where he manages to kill a bear/deer for food and the whole animal carcass gets quickly infested with maggots. This is where he is confronted with the "coldness of life". He eventually dies of hunger.
It was based on a true story. There is also a Wikipedia article on that movie/boy.
Some scenes of that movie are shown in this motivational video on YouTube. 

I think the name of the movie is Into the Wild.
An excerpt from IMDB:

After graduating from Emory University, top student and athlete Christopher McCandless abandons his possessions, gives his entire $24,000 savings account to charity and hitchhikes to Alaska to live in the wilderness. Along the way, Christopher encounters a series of characters that shape his life.

